# Eclipse, tomcat, 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am learning servlets and follow [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html#installation_tomcat) tutorial (I follow step by step but I named the project "SampleServlet" instead of "de.vogella.wtp.filecounter"). When I start the server (step 5.4) I get 404 page error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SampleServlet/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter
type Status report
message /SampleServlet/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter
description The requested resource (/SampleServlet/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter) is not available.
```

Where to start debugging? There were several "INFO" in the console when server started and one warning:

```
29.08.2011 21:03:44 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SampleServlet' did not find a matching property.
```

Do I need to change any preferences?

Comment: Which tutorial? Could you post the Link?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I've corrected the link in the question.

Comment: Could you also post the contens of the "web.xml" file? It seems like the url youre trying to reach is not correctly mapped to your servlet.

Comment: `web.xml` is too long to post it here so I put it on gist - https://gist.github.com/1180501

Comment: That's the `web.xml` of your server! You need to post the one of your webapp. The one in `/WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: `SampleServlet\WebContent\WEB-INF` folder has no `web.xml` file. It contains only `lib` folder.

Comment: In Eclipse, when you create a Servlet 3.0 project and don't tick the "Generate deployment descriptor" checkbox, then a `web.xml` will indeed not be generated. You're supposed to use `@WebServlet` annotation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tutorial is suggesting you to invoke it by http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/FileCounter. The project name defaults to context name `de.vogella.wtp.filecounter` which you've changed to `SampleServlet`, so you need to invoke the servlet by http://localhost:8080/SampleServlet/FileCounter.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

---

As to the `SetPropertiesRule` warning, just ignore it, that's normal. Eclipse is just adding an extra attribute to Tomcat's `<Context>` element to be able to associate the deployed webapp with a particular project. Tomcat is just jerking because it don't recognize it as one of the predefined `<Context>` attributes. It's however trying to be helpful for the case the enduser actually made a typo and so on. Just ignore it. You won't see it when you export the webapp and deploy it on a real production server.

Comment: When I right click on the `FileCounter.java` file in the Project Explorer tab and select "Run As"->"Run on Server" the internal browser opens http://localhost:8080/SampleServlet/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter with 404 error. http://localhost:8080/SampleServlet/FileCounter results with the same error.

Comment: I now understand why you run into problems. That tutorial is targeted on Servlet 2.5 while you've created a Servlet 3.0 project which by default get built without `web.xml`. You would need the `@WebServlet` annotation instead. Put this line `@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/FileCounter"})` on top of the servlet class declaration. And please, undo all changes you made in Tomcat's own `web.xml`. This is not the right way to declare your own servlets, it makes your webapp unportable!

Comment: @BalusC's answer brought me back from the brink of suicide. When creating the servlet from WebContent, simply _don't_ overwrite the auto-generated `@WebServlet("/FileCounter")` annotation in the servlet class.  What I'm still puzzled by is why Eclipse (Indigo) is not appending /FileCounter to the URL... why do we have to add it manually?

Answer (score 5):

Okay according to your web.xml it seems like you're missing a servlet definition and a servlet-mapping. I Don't know why this is not generated by your ide. It should be something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.SampleServlet</servlet-class> <!-- The full qualified package path to your Servlet class -->        
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>SampleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mysample</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the `servlet-mapping` Element you just map any url to your servlet defined above. So if you now call http://yourserver:8080/projectname/mysample the Servlet your.package.SampleServlet will be called.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Please note that the OP posted the `web.xml` of Tomcat itself, not of the webapp.

Comment: Super! That works! I wonder why these changes in `web.xml` file were not generated by Eclipse.

Comment: Please note that you should not edit the `web.xml` of the server! You should edit or create the one of your webapp.

Comment: Yes BalusC is right! Look for the web.xml file located in your project directory under WEB-INF/web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Add FileCounter as one of a welcome-file in web.xml, it's look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>de.vogella.wtp.filecounter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <!-- <welcome-file>FirstJSP.jsp</welcome-file>  -->
    <welcome-file>FileCounter</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FileCounter</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileCounter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileCounter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileCounter</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```